# Way to output differences between two files (preferably using command line)

Tags: comparison, diff

I am familiar with tools such as tkDiff and WinMerge and am aware of how to see the difference between two files.

What I'm looking to do is to produce a report of elements in one file that are not present in another.

For example:

File1 contains:

```
apple
cool
dude
flan
```

File2 contains:

```
apple
ball
cool
dude
elephant
```

I want to produce a report that contains:

```
ball
elephant
```

Or, better yet, a report like this:

```
+ball
+elephant
-flan
```

Does anybody know of a tool that can do this?  Preferably with command line options.

The report feature in WinMerge isn't too far off what I'd like but there is no command line option to do this (as far as I know).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You probably want the [Unix comm utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html). [Windows versions](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) are included in gnuwin32

> NAME
>
> ```
>    comm - compare two sorted files line by line
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.
>
>    With  no    options,  produce  three-column  output.  Column one contains
>    lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to  FILE2,  and
>    column three contains lines common to both files.
>
>    -1     suppress lines unique to FILE1
>
>    -2     suppress lines unique to FILE2
>
>    -3     suppress lines that appear in both files
> ```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for this. The whole GnuWin32 is something I wasn't aware of and is clearly complete GOLD! By using a combination of -1 and -3, I was able to get what I wanted. Shame there's no + and - though but I guess I shouldn't be too greedy.

Comment: A bit of work with sed (also in the utils) should let you add the +/-

Comment: NICE!  I had to do a diff between two datasets, and comparing 1.1 million rows vs 8 million rows was going to take too long.  I dumped to .CSV, and used cygwin:  comm -2 -3 file1.csv file2.csv > out.csv
It ran in 13 seconds!

Comment: Nice answer. but how to save output as a file?

Comment: Redirect it, same as any other CLI command. `comm -1 file1 file2 > results`, for example

Comment: I tried to compare 2 lists of SKUs sorted the same way. It just dumps most of the SKUs in all three columns for me. The first SKU I checked in column 1 appears in column 2 as well. `comm` seems useless to me. Any idea if it's my fault?

Comment: Comm's been around for more than 40 years. I think it's safe to assume it works as documented. Post your issue, with more details, as a separate question.

Comment: If your files are not sorted, you can sort them inline like so: `comm -1 <(sort -u file1.txt) <(sort -u file2.txt)`

Answer (score 47):

This might work for you (GNU diff):

```
diff -u file1 file2 | sed -n '1,2d;/^[-+]/p'
+ball
-flan
+elephant
```

Comment: Excellent. A better answer, since works on unsorted files. The 'sed' addition of +/- is a nice touch (required by the original question).

Answer (score -4):

To compare data with command prompt you can use

**COMP /a /l D:\Folder1\data.txt D:\Folder2\data.txt**

Here are other options to [compare files and folders with command prompt](http://www.funbutlearn.com/2012/10/compare-two-filesfolders-with-command.html).

Comment: I dont see how this answer is relevant to the question.

Comment: I didn't get anything useful from it: "Files are different sizes.". The result I get from [FC](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html) is more useful.